# Can't upload to google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I click the deploy button on SpringSource Tool Suite nothing happens. Same when I try to click "sign in to Google".

Any ideas?

- Got app ID setup
- appengine-web.xml contains matching app id.
- using default SDK - App Engine - 1.5.0 & GWT 2.3.0
- Running Windows 7

Comment: Same here, tried STS 2.7.1 and 2.8.0.M1. Strange...

Comment: Did you get lucky with the issue. I am also facing the same issue, with STS 2.7.1, nothing happens on clicking the deploy button neither on clicking sign in to google button. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are behind a proxy. Have you tried setting your proxy details under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections ?

Comment: Make sure you set it to "manual" and that HTTPS proxy is defined (because GAE will not work with just HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

See this post for the possible resolutions - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5293